# Json decoding and reading

Tags: php, json

I want to make a script to share GameServers stats. I'm using JSON method. How can I read only hostname?

JSON

```
[
    [
        {
            "ip": "176.57.188.22",
            "port": "27022",
            "rank": "1",
            "online": "1",
            "hostname": "..:: LS Public Server ::.. #1",
            "num_players": "12",
            "max_players": "32",
            "location": "AL",
            "mapa": "de_dust2"
        }
    ],
    true
]
```

or link to test it LIVE **[HERE](http://gametracker.al/api.php)**

I wat to read only hostname. I tried too muany methods, but they don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose the JSON string (or object) is stored in the variable `$json`.

```
<?php
// convert your JSON object to a PHP array
$decoded_json = json_decode($json, true);

print_r($decoded_json); // print your PHP array to check how to subindex your new var
// I think it will be something like $decoded_json[0]['hostname']
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
$test = '[
    [
        {
            "ip": "176.57.188.22",
            "port": "27022",
            "rank": "1",
            "online": "1",
            "hostname": "..:: LS Public Server ::.. #1",
            "num_players": "12",
            "max_players": "32",
            "location": "AL",
            "mapa": "de_dust2"
        }
    ],
    true
]';
$test = json_decode($test);
echo $test[0][0]->hostname;
//---output---
//..:: LS Public Server ::.. #1
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with `true` as second parameter, it gives you an associative array and it will convert the JSON object into a PHP array.

**Try this :**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$test = '[
    [
        {
            "ip": "176.57.188.22",
            "port": "27022",
            "rank": "1",
            "online": "1",
            "hostname": "..:: LS Public Server ::.. #1",
            "num_players": "12",
            "max_players": "32",
            "location": "AL",
            "mapa": "de_dust2"
        }
    ],
    true
]';
$data = json_decode($test,true);

foreach ($data as $info) {
    foreach ($info as $result) {
         echo $result[hostname];   
    }
}

?>
```

## [Demo!](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQm04SUE3T1BjRU0)